# CSS unbreakable link

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I'm trying to style an "a" html element so it won't split in 2 parts when it reaches the right-hand end of the block it is places in.

Just in case I have not made myself clear enough here's an example:

I have a body of width 400 px
and I have placed 3 "a" elements, each 150px in length, in it without any line breakers
so naturally I will end up with the first 2 "a" elements next to the starting 100px of the 3rd one on the first row of text,
and finally the 50 px rest of the 3rd "a" on the next row
But i want to create the effect of having the first 2 "a"'s on the first row of text and the entire 3rd "a" on the second row of text.

Lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if i understand you question right => try this

```
.nowrap {white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: Yes dude, of course. It's jsut that 10 minutes have to pass from when the question was posted so I can give you the tick. Don't worry.

Comment: Lol, thats funny! Have a nice day!

Comment: Yays, I just got 15 rep so I upvoted your answear aswell. Upvotes for everyone :D A nice day to you too